# Android, get specific fileld from grid item

Tags: android, gridview

I have GridView with specific GridItem.xml contains a few TextView's

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This GridView will be filled with data from the database.
Now I want to do something like filter which hide items where text in TextView by  id="@+id/title"  not equal to typed myWord,

```
        GridView MyGridView   = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.MyGridView);
        GridViewAdapter gridAdapter  = new GridViewAdapter(Kategorie.this, R.layout.kategorie_grid_item, getData(ds));
        MyGridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

and getData

```
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

        String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
        Map      v = (Map) postSnapshot.getValue();

        String title      = (String) v.get("title");
        String subtitle   = (String) v.get("subtitle");

        myItems.add(new MyItem(title, subtitle));

    }


    return myItems;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I dont know how to get value of title in loop

Answer (score 0):

the list you added it to adapter can you make filtering on it.
can you show how you added item to GridView

Comment: The probelm is not how to hide items, but how to get value of TextView with id "title", in future i would like highlight or distinguish some items with specific values, and i would like do it directly in my loop.

Comment: can you add any implementation in the adapter like can you hide some element in specific position

Comment: OK i have added